# I cannot access the array in the data in mongo.db using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

> I cannot reach the second element of the array in the second row of the data in the orders collection in mongo.db and get their total.Im using Node.js.
> I want to get the "quantity" sums of the last two months.

```
const getMonthlySales = asyncHandler(async (req, res) =\> {

    `const quantity = req.query.pid;
    const date = new Date();
    const lastMonth = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1));
    const previousMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1));
    
    if (req.user.isAdmin) {
    
        try {
            const sales = await OrderController.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        createdAt: {$gte: previousMonth}, ...(quantity && {
                            products: {$elemMatch: {quantity}},
                        })`your text`
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        month: {$month: "$createdAt"},
                        sales: "$quantity",
                    },
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$month",
                        total: {$sum: "$sales"},
                    },
                },
            ]);
`
console.log(sales)
res.status(200).json(sales);
} catch (err) {
res.status(500).json(err);
}
} else {
res.status(403).json("You are not allowed to see monthly income!");
}

});
```

`my data:`

```
_id:ObjectId('6373f7502659c534b4f82d2f')
userId:"6373f3152659c534b4f82c67"
products:Array
   0:Object
       productId:"636792b261e41fa0b30d64d0"
       quantity:3
      _id:ObjectId("6373f7502659c534b4f82d30")
   1:Object
       productId:"636792b261e41fa0b30d64d0"
       quantity:3
      _id:ObjectId("6373f7502659c534b4f82d30")
amount:300
address:"NY"
status:""
createdAt:2022-10-15T20:32:16.675+00:00
updatedAt:2022-10-15T20:32:16.675+00:00
__v:0



id:ObjectId('6373f7502659c534b4f82d2f')
userId:"6373f3152659c534b4f82c67"
products:Array
products:Array
   0:Object
       productId:"636792b261e41fa0b30d64d0"
       quantity:2
      _id:ObjectId("6373f7502659c534b4f82d30")
   1:Object
       productId:"636792b261e41fa0b30d64d0"
       quantity:2
      _id:ObjectId("6373f7502659c534b4f82d30")
amount:300
address:"NY"
status:""
createdAt:2022-11-15T20:32:16.675+00:00
updatedAt:2022-11-15T20:32:16.675+00:00
__v:0
```

> i expected to happen :
> [ {_id: 10, total: 6 }, { _id: 11, total: 4 } ]
> i actually resulted:
> [ {_id: 10, total: 0 }, { _id: 11, total: 0 } ]

Answer (score 2):

Use $unwind on products array, then the total will come as per needed. Shown below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$products"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: {
        "$month": "$createdAt"
      },
      total: {
        "$sum": "$products.quantity"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/nb_1gu5pUjm